# Combining Multiple Data Matrices to a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, merge

I have 4 matrices;
matrix1
matrix2
matrix3
matrix4
and I want to make a list of these 4 in R, 
can you please help?

Comment: `list(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4)`?

Comment: Thx that worked; but if someone has used mlp and RSNNS please advise on how not to have it split your data but use your own training and test sets THX

Comment: I think you should make a separate question for  that. But please, do read through the documentation first. Packages often come with examples and even full manuals (vignettes).

Comment: I am using their manual and that is how I know what they do. But thx If my method does not work I will post a new specific to RSNNS question.

Comment: @sebastian-c, I'd consider your comment the answer to this question. Do you want to post it as such?

Comment: @MvG Consider it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine separate objects into a list, use the `list` function:

```
list(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4)
```